# How to select ids which have two different records?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table in my db with fields: id, application_id and type_id.

I want to select from this table application_id's which have 2 different records in table (one with type_id=2 and second with type_id=4)

How to do it in PostgreSQL?
I can achieve it by group by and having or only with loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select application_id
from t
where type_id in (2, 4)
group by application_id
having min(type_id) <> max(type_id);
```